# Is it possible to create two dimensional array and declare length of each row later?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, dimensions, dimension

Is there any way to declare length of each row later?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] arrr = new int[3][];
    int[] arrr[0] = new int[3];
    int[] arrr[1] = new int[4];
    int[] arrr[2] = new int[5];
}
```

I know in this example it looks unnecessary, but I wanted to show it as simple as possible.

Comment: It's possible but it's bad form - people will usually expect multidimensional arrays to be rectangular. Probably you want a non-array data type (you usually want a non-array data type - arrays are a pain.)

Comment: `arrr[0] = new int[3]; arrr[1] = new int[4]; arrr[2] = new int[5];` -- you don't specify the `int[]` part on the left hand side. It's already declared as a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

"In Java, ArrayList is a resizable implementation."
For arrays of variable size (modifiable at runtime), import and use the ArrayList object.

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    //creating an ArrayList
    ArrayList<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //Adding an element to ArrayList
    grades.add(99); //you'd want to use a Scanner or similar to input grades like this
    
    //Accessing an element of the ArrayList
    System.out.println( grades.get(0) ); //grades[0] equivalent

  }
}
```

This can also be done for 2D dynamic arrays:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    //creating an ArrayList of ArrayLists of ints
    ArrayList< ArrayList<Integer> > grades = new ArrayList<>();
    
    //Adding an element to the list
    grades.at(0).at(0).add(99); //grades[0][0] where the second 0 is dynamically added
    
    //Accessing an element of the list
    System.out.println( grades.at(0).get(0) ); //grades[0][0] equivalent

  }
}
```

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html